# не запускается исполняемый файл wpf проекта на windows xp

Tags: wpf, x86, .net-4.5

в общем, собрал wpf проект на windows 7(.NET 4.5) x86_64 под 32-битную версию... пытаюсь запускать на windows xp x86 - дескать, exe-шник не является Win32 приложением... в чем может быть косяк? .NET 4.0 на xp стоит

Comment: А если поставить 4.5?

Comment: а разве встанет 4.5 то?

Comment: Или скомпилировано под 64 или понизьте до 4.0, слышал, что в XP 4.5 проблема..

Comment: понижать то нельзя, я там async/await насобачил

Comment: Окей, меняем стратегию. А если скомпилировать с таргетом .NET 4.0? Среда вроде ж позволяет?

Comment: да не соберется проект с 4.0 (

Comment: А вы собирайте тем же компилятором, а не старым. По идее должен собрать.

Comment: не, не прокатывает, к сожалению... вычитал, что вообще 4.5 нельзя на xp запустить

Answer (score 1):

Программа, сделанная для 4.5, на 4.0 запускаться не должна (вот наоборот - пожалуйста).

Если нужен запуск под WinXP - собирайте вашу программу под 4.0 (или вообще 2.0/3.5). Только придется поставить некоторые системные классы пакетами из nuget или написать самому.

Для поддержки async/await можно использовать пакет [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/)

также может иметь смысл копирование реализации системных классов из проектов [Reference Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource), [.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) и [Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono). В последнем проекте также имеет смысл поискать в истории старые реализации системных классов, которые сейчас заменены на реализации из первых двух проектов. Ну и не забудьте посмотреть лицензию если будете заниматься копи-пастом.

Comment: понял, спасибо за коммент